# Latex: cite a chapter in a book without parentheses

Tags: latex

I want to cite a chapter in a book like this:

see ABC (2008, Chapter2-3)

So I tried

```
see \cite[Chapter~2-3]{ABC08}
```

but it appears

see (ABC, 2008, Chapter2-3)

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I know now.
I should use `\citet` instead of `\cite`!